# npm install is not working | npm ERR! path | npm ERR! code | npm ERR! errno | npm ERR! syscall | npm ERR! enoent

Tags: npm, npm-install, js-beautify

I've been using the vue-cli for two weeks and everything had been working fine until today. I was setting up this project locally.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwGw1zyyKjW7S3RYWXRaX24tQ3c

When entered **npm install** the following errors appeared

Errors displayed in terminal

[image: Errors displayed in terminal]

I tried deleting the project and doing npm install again with no luck.

I tried installing **beautify-js globally** with no luck.

Also if I enter **vue init webpack-simple *projectName** the same errors will appear.

```
node v8.5.0
npm 5.4.2
```

If you might know something that can help me fix this please let me know.
I haven't been able to proceed in my VueJs course because of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some other people having this issue, I believe there is a problem with the most recent js-beautify

Check this out -> https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247

Comment: Thanks! installing "js-beautify": "1.6.14" solved the issue.

Comment: I got this problem when trying to install Express in a Dropbox folder. I got it to work by making a temp folder outside Dropbox, and installing it there. Then I copied the files back to the Dropbox folder. I have no idea why Dropbox interferes with npm like this...